# Flutter: Layout Card

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working with **Card** , i have some problem with layout . 
So, What i'm expected like this :
[image: Iwant]

But when implement, not what i want , i'm already using 
`mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,` But Not Work

Text  `Disini Judul` always in center Container: 
[image: iwant2]

### It's my Card Code

```
Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 5,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              child: Text('Disini Judul'),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              child: Text('Disini Judul'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Image.network(
                            'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                            width: 150),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Can you help me with this layout ?

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add child in to Container base on you needs

```
           body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        height: 200.0,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                      height: 100.0,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Text(
                          'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Your date'),
                        Text('Your Category')
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              height: double.infinity,
              width: 150.0,
              child: Image.network("https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/funny-face-baby-27701492.jpg",
                fit: BoxFit.fill

              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

[image]

Comment: Your layout color, help me so much. Thank's

Answer (score 0):

you can easily achieve this using Stack widget, have a look at below code

[image]

```
Container(
      height: 180,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
      child: Card(
        elevation: 5,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              child: Text(
                  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500'),
              top: 0,
              right: 150,
              left: 10,
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 10,
              right: 150,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Date: 18-Sep-2019'),
                  Text('Category: Sport')
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                    width: 150),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```